# Central orbit differential equation problems

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image: Example]
I have a problem with the highlighted step in the example, i couldn't quite understand how did he integrate that ?

Answer (score 0):

Both sides of the equation are multiplied by $du/d\theta$ and then integrated with respect to $\theta$ (and multiplied by 2).

I suppose you could call this procedure “integrating with respect to $u$”, but I think that's a rather unclear way of explaining it.

Comment: Can you please go through the steps in more detail, I know it's just 2 steps but when i tried it i didn't quite get it

Comment: It's perhaps easier to do it backwards? Take the derivative of the last equation with respect to $\theta$, using the chain rule (so that $(u^4)'=4u^3 u'$ and $((u')^2)'=2u'u''$, etc.).